# how to get back windows 8 after 12.10 installation

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-8

The UEFI thing screwed my head a bit while trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 in Dell 7520, I made separate partition in Windows 8, installed Ubuntu via liveUSB it went well, but Ubuntu didn't load. So, I hit the Ubuntu install again, it asked me to erase previous Ubuntu, I said yes, now the Ubuntu 12.10 works perfectly.

I used boot-repair to repair the GRUB as suggested in some answers here, and when I reboot, there was no option for windows 8. I booted to Ubuntu to check the Ubuntu have used whole 1 TB (total space). That means I deleted windows ? If so, any way to get the setup back? I don't have repair disk, nor DVD. Win8 came pre-installed.

Edit:

For the ones who are looking for such solutions, there is NO WAY to get it back, at-least in my kind of situation. I again installed the windows from DVD (I got it from Dell Customer Center, and while purchasing this Laptop I had one month of premium support, which made things easier).

I installed windows8 with DVD and not selecting UEFI and I used G-Parted from LiveUSB to create partitions, Hence, installed Ubuntu 12.10 in other partition via LiveUSB.

Comment: Unfortunately as far as I know there is nothing we here at Ask Ubuntu can do in this situation. An easy solution to this is to request a restoration CD from Dell. I have been in this situation and Dell are (usually) more than happy to supply a Windows install disc via post. Thanks.

Comment: yes I checked that option, this facility is provided only in US... I am in Europe.... They should have such facility here too if they are selling their computer here....

Comment: That's strange since I also do not live in the US.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you deleted your Windows partition.  However I predict you don't have your GRUB menu set up correctly.  First to verify that you havn't deleted your Windows partition type:
`sudo fdisk -l`
look for one that has NTFS as the file system type this is most likely your windows partition:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/hdb1   *           1        2432    19535008+  86  NTFS
/dev/hdb2            2433        2554      979965   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/hdb3            2555        6202    29302560   83  Linux
```

In this example it is /dev/hdb1

Once you verify that it is still existent(hopefully it is) you will need add it to your grub menu.  I recommend you check out this link:

http://technologytales.com/2010/11/21/manually-adding-an-entry-for-windows-7-to-an-ubuntu-grub2-menu/

Because it varies slightly depending your windows partition name also check out the first entry in this:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1817827

If in fact you did delete your windows partition I recommend you call and get another CD from the manufacturer.  They will usually send them to you for free since the windows CD key should be on a sticker on your computer.

Comment: thanks for your response... but it looks like i screwed it... I don't have NTFS, just Linux, Extended, Linux swap / solaris. I'll ask them for CD...