# After installing Ubuntu 12.10, Windows 8.1 disappears from start up menu

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-8

I'm very new to Ubuntu (12.10), so I apologise if I'm not clear at any point!

I had a Windows 8 (upgraded to Windows 8.1) and was fed up with it, so I converted to Ubuntu 12.10. I'd hoped to Dual Boot to at least get the benefit of both worlds.

I created a partition for it in Windows and installed from a LiveUSB key (and installed into that parition). So now Ubuntu works great, but Windows 8.1 no longer shows up on the start up screen (where you theoretically pick which OS you want to boot in).

I was going to try "Boot Repair" as mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and restore MBR, but I don't want to start messing around with stuff I'm not entirely clear with.

EDIT:

For any of those who stumble here with the same problem, I just read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256632/how-to-get-back-windows-8-after-12-10-installation?rq=1) that a user wiped out his Windows partition by accident...

I checked my own computer with `sudo fdisk -l` and there's only one Device Boot (dev/sda1). I'm not an expert, but I'm guessing that means Windows has been written over.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read on your explanation it sounds like you did erase your windows installation. I would suggest you read this:

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported
```

And from personal experience I would suggest when you are planning on dual booting, always install windows first and linux last. Linux works well with other operating systems, but windows has a tendency to not play along well. What happened to me was that it would not show an option to start linux, and many times it would also try and remove linux altogether, so understanding partitioning helps, but installing linux last helps even more X_x

Comment: Thanks! I'll bear that in mind when I go to reinstall - I'm getting the feeling this could be quite a difficult repair... Did you manage to successfully dual boot in the end?